# SQL Newbie -  Unsure how to write query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables involved:
Units
Types
Factions

Units has a foreign key from Types and Factions (TypeID and FactionID).
I need to get Units.UnitName, using Types.TypeName and Factions.FactionName.

I think I may need a join, but I'm unsure how to structure it. Any help?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the tables in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4fVJ.png

I need to return this data:
UnitName - SupplyCost - CreditsCost - MetalCost - CrystalCost

The form to get this information will provide FactionName and TypeName, as they are text values and therefore easily understandable by a user, as opposed to numeric IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
select UnitName, SupplyCost, CreditsCost, MetalCost, CrystalCost from Units
inner join Types on Types.TypeID = Units.TypeID 
inner join Factions on Faction.FactionID = Units.FactionID
WHERE Types.TypeName = @typeName
AND Factions.FactionName = @factionName
```

Comment: Updated the question - please give it a look

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Units.UnitName
FROM Units INNER JOIN Types ON Units.TypeId = Types.TypeId
    INNER JOIN Factions ON Units.FactionId = Factions.FactionId
WHERE Types.TypeName = @typeName
    AND Factions.FactionName = @factionName
```

Would that be what you are after? If not, you may need to provide more info in your question.

Comment: he wants to select the typename and factionname, not filter on it (at least... thats how i read the question)

Comment: @amaters He says he "needs to get Units.UnitName", so that would imply it is only output. "using Types....etc.", so to me this meant they are a filter condition. Of course, it is a bit of a vague question, so it is up to interpretation.

Comment: I'd sorry if I haven't gotten the question through that well. Databases are my weakest skill :(

Comment: Updated the question - please give it a look

Comment: @amaters So it looks like this was the right answer, but just needed some additional return fields which weren't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: yes, in the end the combination of answers was the one Michael Heffernan was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check it

```
select UnitName, SupplyCost, CreditsCost, MetalCost, CrystalCost from Units
inner join Types on Types.TypeID = Units.TypeID 
inner join Factions on Faction.FactionID = Units.FactionID
WHERE Types.TypeName = @typeName
AND Factions.FactionName = @factionName
```

Comment: I think you made a typo there with the inner join on Factions: you compare Units.UnitId with FactionId

Comment: Updated the question - please give it a look

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   SupplyCost, CreditsCost, MetalCost, CrystalCost
FROM
   Units 
      INNER JOIN Types ON Units.TypeID = Types.TypeId
      INNER JOIN Factions ON Units.FactionId = Factions.TypeId
WHERE 
      Types.TypeName = 'value from form for types'
      AND
      Factions.FactionName = 'value from form for factions'
```

You can read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html for a nice and visual explanation of JOIN

Comment: Updated the question - please give it a look